# In the stern-Gerlach experiement how do we know that the magnets don't change orientation of the electrons to up or down?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I watched this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg4Fnag4V-E

Say the electron's north pole started off 60 degrees from the south pole, since the electron has little mass wouldn't that make it easy for the magnet to turn it perpendicular to the south pole?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the electron is acted upon by a torque $ \vec{\tau} = \vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}  $, how does it deviate the path of the incoming electrons? To do such a task, you need a force. Where does that force come from? The force comes from this equation: $ \vec{F} = -\vec{ \nabla }U  $ where $ U = -  \vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B }  $. If the magnetic field $ \vec{B}$ is aligned along say some z-axis, i.e. if $ \vec{B}=B_{z} \space \vec{e_z}$, then this equation tells you that the force is always directed along the z-axis and is proportional to the magnitude of the component of the magnetic moment of the electron along the z-axis (substitute and check that $ \vec{F} = \mu_{z} \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z} \vec{e_z}$). It does not matter whether there are components of the magnetic moment along other axes, the force is always proportional to the z-component and directed along that axis.

The Stern Gerlach experiment does not tell you that $ \vec{\mu} = \mu_z \vec{e_z}$, but that $\mu_z$ is quantized to two fixed values. From a classical perspective, we would expect a continuum of values. That does not happen. So we get spin-up and spin-down electrons corresponding to the two fixed values for $\mu_z$. This is from the perspective of the z-axis mind you! We don't know what happens with the components of the moment along the other axes. If we make the spin-up electrons (which are deflected in a certain direction) go through another S-G setup which probes $\mu_x$ say, then we will see that half of them are spin-up along x, and half are spin-down along x. If we make one of these beams go through yet another S-R setup that probes $\mu_z$, classically we expect to get only spin-up electrons 100% of the times, because that is what we started with. But we get 50% spin-up and 50% spin-down.

Two things need explanation: (1) the quantization of space, that is the absence of a continuum of values for $\mu_z$, and (2) the loss of memory of a previous measurement when a new measurement is made. These things cannot be explained classically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you are fighting here a little bit with quantum mechanics. The electron has a mass, yes, but it is not a rigid object that you can turn, nor is the magnetic moment a property bound to the mass such that you could turn it. It is also difficult to say it has a certain direction in space. If you look at the qm equation, it has actually a direction, but this is nothing you can access from your macroscopic world. We measure expectation values. Hence, we can only measure the projection of the spin on a quantization axis, given by the magnetic field. Eventually, as the magnetic moment of the electron is considered angular momentum, the field does not turn it as it would a classical moment. The field results in a torque and a classical moment would turn. Angular momentum, however, will precess, even in classical mechanics.

Note that the fact that qm only allows for measuring the projection of the magnetic moment on the quantization axis, is actually the clue of the SG-experiment. It is either +1/2 or -1/2. There are no "angles" in-between. It is quantized.

Comment: "Ok, I think you are fighting here a little bit with quantum mechanics." You cannot fight with 'quantum mechanics', you can only fight the interpretation of evidence. What is the problem with questioning an interpretation of evidence? You should embrace these questions, even if they are from amateurs like me. It is important to respect authority but not necessarily agree with it just because 'they are the experts', I am ignorant that is why I ask this question. Anyway you say "The electron has a mass, yes, but it is not a rigid object that you can turn" What evidence suggests this?

Comment: @RayKay, I suggest you check your premises.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri What are you referring to exactly? The premise you made but did not explain?: "The electron has a mass, yes, but it is not a rigid object that you can turn" if that is the case that is not my premise but yours. I cannot see any premise I made where the conclusion does not jump out at you Eg: "You cannot fight with 'quantum mechanics', you can only fight the interpretation of evidence." ". It is important to respect authority but not necessarily agree with it just because 'they are the experts"

Comment: @RayKay I don't have problems with simple questions from non-experts (look at my activities) I have a problem with aggressive comments, though, and I will just assume that you have the most friendly intentions. Now to physics: from your question it is not clear that we are talking about "interpretation of evidence". I answered your question within the limits of quantum mechanics. I is a theory describing most of the subatomic phenomena and can be considered quite robust. Nevertheless, nobody knows the "true" radius of an electron and a better theory with "rotating electron masses" might exist.

Comment: And by the way, I think it works the other way around. The fact that you do not observe a continuous distribution in experiment, tells you 1: it is quantized and 2: related to angular momentum. Again, note that if we have angular momentum, even in classical mechanics it would not turn but precess.